# Boost spirit or order

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, rule

I would like to create a boost spirit rule that parses a string and an float. The strings I would like to parse are formatted like this:

```
(str astring)(n 123)
```

or could also be in another order:

```
(n 123)(str astring)
```

I would like to create a rule with an attribute of following type:

```
qi::rule<Iter, boost::fusion::vector<std::string, float>, ascii::space_type> hj;
```

So far this is my code:

```
qi::rule<Iter, std::string(), ascii::space_type> attr;
attr = lexeme[*alnum];

qi::rule<Iter, boost::fusion::vector<std::string, float>, ascii::space_type> hj;
hj = (
         '(' >> lit("str") >> attr(/*put this at position 0*/) >> ')'
     |
         '(' >> lit("n") >> float_[/*put this at position 1*/] >> ')'
     );
```

Obviously, this does not compile (boost deducts another attribute type). How can I implement  this, especially, what would I put in the commented code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the permutation operator `^`. Minimum working example:

```
boost::fusion::vector<std::string,float> ans;
bool res = phrase_parse(first,last,
            (lit("(") >> lit("str") >> lexeme[*ascii::alnum] >> lit(")") ) ^
            (lit("(") >> lit("n") >> float_ >> lit(")") ),
            ascii::space,ans);
```

This solution is described with more detail [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/02/17/parsing-arbitrary-things-in-any-sequence/).

Comment: +1.[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b0a0abfe1669615) is a complete example. It's important to note that the permutation parser also matches a single `(n number)` or a single `(str string)` filling with a default constructed element the one that is missing.